# How to send delete request to REST api using angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How to send delete request to REST api using angular?

I want send delete with id: 1

I try:

```
this.http.delete(environment.apiUrl+"id="+1).subscribe(data => {

});
```

Where http is `private http: HttpClient`, but it not working.

Value of environment.apiUrl is http://localhost/deleteendpoint

Comment: That URL looks strange. What is the value of `environment.apiUrl`?

Comment: Value of environment.apiUrl is http://localhost/deleteendpoint

Comment: So maybe a `?` is missing. Try with `this.http.delete(environment.apiUrl+"?id="+1).subscribe(data=>{});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const params = new HttpParams().set('id', '1');

this.http.delete(environment.apiUrl, { params })
  .subscribe(
    result => console.log(result),
    err => console.error(err)
  );
```

Try the above - sorry for poor answer format, on mobile :)

Comment: It seems like the *HttpParams* object isn't present in *@angular/http*. Where is it located? I'm running Angular 5 now and there's something about  *RequestOptions* - not sure if it's of importance...

Comment: It comes from the new HttpClient, so import {HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
this.http.delete(this.environment.apiUrl/+1).subscribe(data => {

});
```