# how can I call a delete method properly?

Tags: angular, http-headers, httprequest, http-delete, delete-method

It's actually the first time that I'm trying to call a delete method angular.
my code in my dataService is:

```
deleteMeaningItem(data): Observable<Result> {
    return this.http.delete<Result>(url, data);
  }
```

and in component:

```
 this.dataService.deleteMeaningItem({id: id}).subscribe(res => {
 if (res.status) {
    //do something          
  }
  });
```

but I'm getting 415 Unsupported Media Type error!
I've also tried to send Content-Type in my request header like:

```
deleteMeaningItem(data): Observable<Result> {
     return this.http.delete<Result>(global.dataUrl + '/MeaningItems/Delete', { params: data,
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}});
}
```

but then then I'm getting 400 Bad Request error!
I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all I had to do was to provide body in the request option. so I did this:

```
deleteMeaningItem(meaningId): Observable<Result> {
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: meaningId,
    };
    return this.http.delete<Result>(global.dataUrl + '/MeaningItems/Delete', options);
  }
```

Comment: Also there is another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47743638/1474613)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is might be in the `data` object. I will first check the docs of the API because it looks like you are missing also `Autorization` header that is usually needed for methods like `delete`

Comment: I've already provided Authorization header in all my requests and that is not the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's easier using RXJS.

First define the delete function @ Service

```
delete(id: string): Observable<Result> {
 return this.httpClient.delete<Result>(`${global.dataUrl}/MeaningItems/${id}`);
}
```

Then try to call it like this:

```
this.service.delete(id).pipe(
  tap(r => console.log('success', r)),
  catchError(e => {
    console.error('error', e);
    return throwError(e);
  })
).subscribe();
```